# Let's encrypt renewal error

Tags: python, certificates, letsencrypt

I run the following from cron every month, and got this error:

```
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto certonly --quiet --standalone --renew-by-default -d example.org -d www.example.org  
Creating virtual environment...
Installing Python packages...     
Installation succeeded.               
An unexpected error occurred:             
DistributionNotFound: The 'ndg-httpsclient' distribution was not found and is required by requests                               
Please see the logfile 'certbot.log' for more details.
```

Clearly, "example" is not my domain, I used the correct one. The `certbot.log` does not offer any more details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/letsencrypt/certbot/main.py", line 858, in main
    plugins = plugins_disco.PluginsRegistry.find_all()
  File "/opt/letsencrypt/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 183, in find_all
    plugin_ep = PluginEntryPoint(entry_point)
  File "/opt/letsencrypt/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.plugin_cls = entry_point.load()
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2201, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2218, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 830, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
DistributionNotFound: The 'ndg-httpsclient' distribution was not found and is required by requests
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Should this be migrated to serverfault? I am never sure when a question should go here or there…

Comment: Could even be OnT on Superuser, this looks like a python dependency problem. (Serverfault might argue "LetsEncrypt is not a professional-grade solution for your certs, hence OffT")

Comment: Have you tried `pip install ndg_httpsclient`? Or `apt-get install python-ndg-httpsclient` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Iskar: Yes, and it works fine. Certbot does its own virtual environment so it is possible the problem is therein.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your operating system but on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, installing the python-ndg-httpsclient package solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install python-ndg-httpsclient
```

I realize this answer may be a little late.

Comment: This is what @iskar suggested in his comment… This did not solve my problem. To be fair, I fixed my problem but cannot remember for the life of me how… ☹